# Como sumar decimales de un registro de Mysql con php?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, pdo

Tengo un pequeño inconveniente es sobre sumar el total de un campo de la base de datos que esta de tipo **DOUBLE(6,3)**.

He tratado con **number_format** y **money_format.**

Un ejemplo es cuando voy a registrar el campo, coloco 240 y cuando se guarda el valor es: 240.000 que es el resultado que quiero. Pero ahora quiero obtener la suma total de todos los registros de ese campo pero el resultado no me lo separa con puntos y comas. me lo da entero y eso es lo que no qiero .Lo que tengo hasta ahora es esto:

```
<?php

require_once "modelo/Conectar.php";

$con=Conectar::conexion();

$sql=$con->query("select sum(monto) from prestamo");

$cons=$sql;

setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'it_IT');
echo money_format('%.2n', $cons);
?>
```

Comment: Si puedes, cambia el tipo de datos a [`DECIMAL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html), es el tipo recomendado para evitar dolores de cabeza cuando trabajas con cantidades monetarias.

Comment: @A.Cedano Hola, me podrías dar un ejemplo de como seria para que un dato me lo de asi: 32,290.000? Pues he intentado con `DECIMAL` 5,2 y 6,3 pero no consigo el resultado que quiero, se te agradecería.

Answer (score 2):

Este sería un ejemplo de tabla usando [`DECIMAL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html). Aquí `20` representaría el número máximo de dígitos y `3` el número de dígitos decimales en el campo.

#### Crear tabla

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS decimal_20170827 (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
descripcion VARCHAR(255),
precio DECIMAL( 20, 3 ) NOT NULL);
```

#### Insertar

Insertarías los datos usando solamente el punto de separación de decimales, los separadores de miles no son necesarios, ya que sólo se usan en el formato.

```
INSERT INTO decimal_20170827(descripcion,precio)
VALUES 
('Moto', 300599.010),
('Auto Seat',1000000.999),
('Bicicleta',1000.002);
```

#### Formatear datos en el SELECT

Veamos un SELECT con varias posibilidades:

```
SELECT  id, 
        descripcion, 
        precio, 
        FORMAT(precio, 3) as normal, 
        FORMAT(precio, 3, 'en_US') as en_US,
        FORMAT(precio, 3, 'es_ES') as es_ES 
        FROM decimal_20170827;
```

Haciendo el `SELECT` sin ningún formato, como es el caso de la columna `precio`, te dará los datos tal cual están almacenados, sin ningún formato. El `FORMAT(precio, 3) as normal` te dará los datos con tres dígitos decimales, usando el formato por defecto del sistema. Puedes aplicar también [formatos locales](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locale-support.html), como muestra `FORMAT(precio, 3, 'en_US')` y `FORMAT(precio, 3, 'es_ES')`

El resultado de la consulta anterior sería:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [descripcion] => Moto
            [precio] => 300599.010
            [normal] => 300,599.010
            [en_US] => 300,599.010
            [es_ES] => 300599,010
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [descripcion] => Auto Seat
            [precio] => 1000000.999
            [normal] => 1,000,000.999
            [en_US] => 1,000,000.999
            [es_ES] => 1000000,999
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [descripcion] => Bicicleta
            [precio] => 1000.002
            [normal] => 1,000.002
            [en_US] => 1,000.002
            [es_ES] => 1000,002
        )

)
```

---

#### `Código completo:` [`Ver Demo`](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/7fqp-sd3f)

```
<?php

/**
 * Consulta con PDO 
 * 
 * Notas: 
 * 1. Los require indicados solo sirven para este ejemplo
 * 2. La consulta  SQL y el  resultado  son sólo para mostrar  un ejemplo , 
 *    cada uno debe adaptarla  a sus necesidades
*/

require_once "dBug!.php";

require "util/public_db_info.php";

$connect = new PDO($dsn, $user_name, $pass_word);

//SQL 
$sqlCreate = 
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS decimal_20170827 (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    descripcion VARCHAR(255),
    precio DECIMAL( 20, 3 ) NOT NULL
);";    


$sqlInsert=
    "INSERT INTO decimal_20170827(descripcion,precio)
     VALUES('Moto', 300599.010),('Auto Seat',1000000.999),('Bicicleta',1000.002);";

//Enviar la consulta a la BD  usando  query->  (hay otros formas de hacerlo, ver ayuda de PHP)

$connect->query($sqlCreate);
//$connect->query($sqlInsert);


$sqlSelect=
    "SELECT id, descripcion, precio, 
            FORMAT(precio, 3) as normal, 
            FORMAT(precio, 3, 'en_US') as en_US,
            FORMAT(precio, 3, 'es_ES') as es_ES 
            FROM decimal_20170827";
$result = $connect->query($sqlSelect);


/**
 * Se crea un array asociativo  de los  resultados usando fecht-> y se almacena en $datos
 *  Hay otras formas de almacenar el  resultado según las  necesidades...
 *  Ver ayuda de PHP para  otras variantes de  fetch
*/ 
$datos = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//Se verifica que la consulta  devolvió valores
if ($datos)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($datos);
    echo "</pre>";


}else{
 print_r("No se encontraron datos, verifique su conexión o la consulta enviada");   
}

//Se cierra la conexión PDO
$connect = null;

?>
```

---

**PD:** Los formatos se pueden aplicar también usando PHP si fuese necesario.

Comment: El resultado que quiero es con coma y punto, pero en formatos locales no me funciona me sale un error y busque pero dicen que windows no lo acepta. Entonces no he logrado al resultado deseado.

Comment: @Juanzu a mi me funciona perfectamente haciéndolo desde MySQL. Si, como dices, no funciona, aplica el formato desde PHP usando [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php). Por ejemplo: `number_format($precio, 3, '.', ',');` en este caso `$precio ` representaría los valores de la columna `precio`. Por ejemplo, este valor: `300599.010` quedaría representado así: `300,599.010`

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(monto), 2) suma
FROM prestamo;
```

Confirmame si te sirve

Saludos

Comment: Ya lo habia hecho asi, por lo menos me sale asi: 32290.00    yo quiero que me lo separece asi: 3,229.000